# Getting value from a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have set a cookie using the following and it works well. I can see it in browser cookie(console).

But how can i get back the value from cookie ??

```
days = 1;
cookiename = 'uid';
cookieValue = result.pp.uid;                        
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}else var expires = "";
document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + cookieValue + expires + "; path=/";
```

I have the following code , but i dont want to use the function.

```
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
```

Ive no idea of how they are getting the value of cookie..

Is there a simple way like document.cookie ?

Comment: ive stripped off the fucntion and ended up with the following and it works.. but there ought to be a simpler way?

var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){
       uid = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
      }
  };

Answer (score 0):

Try this library

```
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
```

Also see this SO post 
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Example from their docs

```
Read cookie:

$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

Comment: this would be dependant on the external plugin right. What i am searching for is whether there is much simpler way(default method) to get the value of cookie using javascript.